# DNS with centos

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, hostname

I have a centos box from linode and I have set the `/etc/hosts` `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/resolv.conf` to only one domain.

Is it okay to host multiple domains on the same machine, while only one domain is configured with the above?

For example if I have `hostname.mydomain.com` as the main domain, and have a few vhosts under apache `somedomain.com` and `somedomain42.com` is this still a correct setup?

Also I found `http://freedns.afraid.org/`. Should I use it for my domain? Is it good to use an external DNS instead of my registrars DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the OS that would cause that setup to be wrong.  Whatever software you're using to provide services on those domain names might require that some of those local services know about the other domains.  Without knowing what software that might be, there's no way for us to answer.

Comment: phpbb mainly.  I do wonder how reseller servers handle multiple domains though. I'm not a reseller but I do host 3 forums on the same server.